# Efficient way to do column level operation in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets

dataset 1:

```
id  a    b      c     d
1  0.3  0.1   0.2   0.2
2  0.2  0.3   0.3   0.4
3  0.2  0.4   0.7   0.7
....
```

dataset2

```
id  x    
1   8  
2   4 
3   10  
....
```

I would like to do an operation, to use the "x" column in the dataset2 times each columns in dataset1, foe each id, so that the desired output is:

```
id   a    b    c    d
1   2.4   0.8  1.6  1.6
2   0.8   1.2  1.2  1.6
3    2     4    7    7
```

What I did is map each row in the dataset1, by joining dataset2

```scala
val result = dataset1.join(dataset2, Seq("id")
                     .map(row=> row.getAs[String]("id"),
                          row=> row.getAs[Double]("a") * row.getAs[Int]("x"),
                          row=> row.getAs[Double]("b") * row.getAs[Int]("x"),
                          row=> row.getAs[Double]("c") * row.getAs[Int]("x"),
                          row=> row.getAs[Double]("d") * row.getAs[Int]("x"))
```

I feel such writing is kind of redundant. Is there any way to get it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `select`:

```scala
dataset1.join(dataset2, Seq("id")).select(
  $"id", $"a" * $"x", $"b" * $"x", $"c" * $"x", $"d" * "x"
).toDF("id", "a", "b", "c", "d")
```

which can be generalized

```scala
val exprs = $"id" +: dataset1.columns.tail.map(c => (col(c) * $"x").alias(c))
dataset1.join(dataset2, Seq("id")).select(exprs: _*)
```